# Rabbitmq kombu consumer queue losing binding to Exchange after some time

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I have a strange problem with my Kombu created queues. After some time they just stop getting messages. no error, but the messages aren't received any more. When I unbind the queue (from the rabbitmq web interface) and rebind it to the same exchange and routing key, everything is working again, for some time.. and then again.

What Am I missing here? I'll be glad for help with this.
I thought maybe I should adding heartbeat? something else?

this is the class the listener uses to create the queue and listen to it:

```
class UpdaterMixin(object):
    #  binding management commands to event names
    #  override in subclass
    event_handlers = {}
    app_name = ''   #override in subclass

    def __init__(self):
        if not self.app_name or len(self.event_handlers) == 0:
            print('app_name or event_handlers arent implemented')
            raise NotImplementedError()
        else:
            self.connection_url = settings.BROKER_URL
            self.exchange_name = settings.BUS_SETTINGS['exchange_name']
            self.exchange_type = settings.BUS_SETTINGS['exchange_type']
            self.routing_key = settings.ROUTING_KEYS[self.app_name]

    def start_listener(self):
        logger.info('started %s updater listener' % self.app_name)\\
        with Connection(self.connection_url) as connection:
            exchange = Exchange(self.exchange_name, self.exchange_type, durable=True)
            queue = Queue('%s_updater' % self.app_name, exchange=exchange, routing_key=self.routing_key)
            with connection.Consumer(queue, callbacks=[self.process_message]) as consumer:
                while True:
                    logger.info('Consuming events')
                    connection.drain_events()

    def process_message(self, body, message):


        logger.info('data received: %s' % body)
        handler = self.event_handlers[body['event']]
        logger.info('Executing management command: %s' % str(handler))
        handler(body)
        message.ack()
```

Rabbitmq version: 3.2